# matrix and vector to 3-d array R

Tags: arrays, r

I have a `i x j` matrix of 1/0. Each row represents an individual 
and columns are visits (elements Y/N).

`A<-matrix(rbinom(21,1,.5), nc=3, nr=7)`

There is a vector denoting an individual's group

`b<-c(1,2,2,1,1,2,3)`

I want to make a 3-d array with dimensions `i x j x max(b)`.

`M<-array(NA, c(nrow(A),ncol(A),max(b)))`

Then fill in `M` from the top row down with the associated 1/0 row
for that individual and survey. Leave any extra rows on the end as NA.

Thanks. I hope this makes some sense.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question, do you want something like this?

```
A<-matrix(rbinom(21,1,.5), nc=3, nr=7)
b<-c(1,2,2,1,1,2,3)
M<-array(NA, c(nrow(A),ncol(A),max(b)))
for (i in unique(b)) {
    M[seq_along(which(b == i)), , i] = A[which(b == i), ]
}
```

Comment: Almost. I want M filled from the top row down,  so all NA rows are at the end. For example ,,1 should have the first three rows filled and the last four rows as NA

Comment: @Nathan - can you just create `M` - even if by hand using `array` - and then add that to your question? It will make things a lot clearer for future readers.

Comment: see the edit, using `seq_along` around the which argument changes it in a vector of `1:length(which(b == i))`.